# How to instance a ViewModel class automatically with Hilt when I use Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

The Code A is from the end branch of the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

The project use *Hilt* to implement dependency injection.

In my mind, I needn't to instance a `ViewModel` class manually when I use  *Hilt*, and the system will automatically instance a `ViewModel` when it needs.

But It seems that the author use the code  `viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()` to instance the `ViewModel` class manually in Code A， how can I  instance a `ViewMode` class automatically with *Hilt* when I use Compose?

**Code A**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun CraneHomeContent(
    onExploreItemClicked: OnExploreItemClicked,
    openDrawer: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
    ...
}



@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    @DefaultDispatcher private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt)

> The viewModel() function mentioned in the ViewModel section
> automatically uses the ViewModel that Hilt constructs with the
> @HiltViewModel annotation. We've provided documentation with
> information about Hilt's ViewModel integration.

So as long as your viewmodel has the @HiltViewModel annotation, you don’t have to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

As @Karim0x1 said. The [Official Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt) guides us like so:

> The viewModel() function mentioned in the ViewModel section automatically uses the ViewModel that Hilt constructs with the @HiltViewModel annotation. We've provided documentation with information about [Hilt's ViewModel integration](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodels).

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val repository: ExampleRepository
) : ViewModel() { /* ... */ }

@Composable
fun ExampleScreen(
    exampleViewModel: ExampleViewModel = viewModel()
) { /* ... */ }
```